# Replace values in a column of a df all at the same time

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very simple problem. I have a large dataframe. And I need to replace values in a column 2 (cluster) following this schema:

```
1 -> 3
2 -> 5
3 -> 1
5 -> 2

> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Target = c("TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i3.mrna1", 
"TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i5.mrna1", "TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i6.mrna1", 
"TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i9.mrna1", "TRINITY_GG_100016_c0_g1_i1.mrna1", 
"TRINITY_GG_100016_c0_g1_i2.mrna1"), cluster = c(2L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), AAA = c(9L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

#normally I will do it like this:
df$cluster[df$cluster == 1]  <- 3
```

The problem is that once I change 1 for 3, the next time I got to change 3 for 1 that will change it again. So I can't approach this sequentially. I need something that will use the original number and change them all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a named vector and replace

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(cluster = coalesce(setNames(c(3, 5, 1, 2),
         c(1, 2, 3, 5))[as.character(cluster)], cluster))
```

-output

```
#                            Target cluster AAA
#1 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i3.mrna1       5   9
#2 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i5.mrna1       2   7
#3 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i6.mrna1       2   8
#4 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i9.mrna1       1   7
#5 TRINITY_GG_100016_c0_g1_i1.mrna1       4   5
#6 TRINITY_GG_100016_c0_g1_i2.mrna1       2   5
```

One of the drawbacks is that it will return `NA` for elements that are not in the named vector.  Inorder to return the original vector values whereever there are `NA`s returned, wrap with `coalesce` so that if there is a `NA` in the updated column, the corresponding value of the old vector is returned

---

Or can do a join with a key/value dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[data.frame(cluster = c(1, 2, 3, 5), new = c(3, 5, 1, 2)), 
     cluster := new, on = .(cluster)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `match` + `ifelse`

```
p <- c(1,2,3,5)
q <- c(3,5,1,2)
transform(
  df,
  cluster = ifelse(cluster %in% q,p[match(cluster,q)],cluster)
)
```

gives

```
                            Target cluster AAA
1 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i3.mrna1       5   9
2 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i5.mrna1       2   7
3 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i6.mrna1       2   8
4 TRINITY_GG_100011_c0_g1_i9.mrna1       1   7
5 TRINITY_GG_100016_c0_g1_i1.mrna1       4   5
6 TRINITY_GG_100016_c0_g1_i2.mrna1       2   5
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly and nice to know the R base option for the future.